# Disable future dates in Bootstrap 3 Datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, date, datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I'm using [Bootstrap 3 Datetimepicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) and I need to disable all my future dates, I know it has it's own `disabledDates` function but I tried so many times and it's still not working.

What am I doing wrong?

```
$('#data_move').datetimepicker({
    language: 'pt-BR',
    disabledDates: [
        moment("22/02/2017")
    ]
});
```

Comment: http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/#minmaxdate

Comment: Maybe it's me but I'm missing the relevance of a link to the functions page with no other context offered.  A useful link would have been: http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#minmaxdate

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should use [`maxDate`](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#maxdate) option instead of `disabledDates`.

Here a working example:

```js
$('#data_move').datetimepicker({
  locale: 'pt-br',
  maxDate: moment()
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/locale/pt-br.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class='input-group date' id='data_move'>
  <input type='text' class="form-control" />
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Does the snippet work for you? Are you sure that you are using eonasdan datetimepicker?

Comment: yes, it worked, and I'm using the datetimepicker I mentioned for sure

Comment: Ok, I fear that you have to watch what are the differences between your environment and the working snippet. It's difficult to give further help with the current information.

Comment: How to disable only specifics dates in datetimepicker e.g an array of random dates?

Comment: @AmirKhan you can use [disabledDates](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#endisableddates) as shown in the original question.

Comment: I am using bootstrap4 datepicker in React JS. I have used type="date" for the date of birth and i do not want user to be able to select current or future dates. How can i do so?

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#data_move').datetimepicker({               
            maxDate: new Date
        });
```

Try this it will work.